# Evaluation of complex integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I am currently working on my thesis in electromagnetism and I have to evaluate the following complex integrals :

$
U = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\frac{e^{i(a\sqrt{\lambda^2-k_1^2}+b\sqrt{\lambda^2-k_2^2})}}{\sqrt{\lambda^2-k_1^2}+\sqrt{\lambda^2-k_2^2}}H_0^{(1)}(\lambda\rho)\lambda d\lambda}$

$V = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\frac{e^{i(a\sqrt{\lambda^2-k_1^2}+b\sqrt{\lambda^2-k_2^2})}}{k_2^2\sqrt{\lambda^2-k_1^2}+k_1^2\sqrt{\lambda^2-k_2^2}}H_0^{(1)}(\lambda\rho)\lambda d\lambda}$

Where $\rho$, $a$ and $b$ are reals numbers, $k_{1/2}$ are the complex wave numbers, and $H_0^{(1)}$ the Hankel function of first kind. $\lambda$ is the complex variable of integration.

I have found in several articles that evaluation is rather complex and the process is never fully shown. That's why I need some hints and tips to complete the evaluation.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: I'm trying to apply a method called "Steepest Descent Path" but i didn't get any result